# IUICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout drag and drop feature: A cell below the cell being long pressed is getting moved

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uicollectionviewlayout

I have attached the following gesture recogniser to my collection view:

```
public void AttachLongPressGestureRecognizer()
        {
            // Create a custom gesture recognizer
            var longPressGesture = new UILongPressGestureRecognizer((gesture) =>
            {
                // Take action based on state
                switch (gesture.State)
                {
                    case UIGestureRecognizerState.Began:
                        var selectedIndexPath = this.MyCollectionView.IndexPathForItemAtPoint(gesture.LocationInView(View));

                        if (selectedIndexPath != null)
                        {
                            this.MyCollectionView.BeginInteractiveMovementForItem(selectedIndexPath);
                        }
                        break;

                    case UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed:
                        this.MyCollectionView.UpdateInteractiveMovement(gesture.LocationInView(View));
                        break;

                    case UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended:
                        this.MyCollectionView.EndInteractiveMovement();
                        break;

                    default:
                        this.MyCollectionView.CancelInteractiveMovement();
                        break;
                }

            });
```

While the drag and drop feature seems to be working, but the selectedIndexPath received is incorrect. When I long press a particular cell, a cell below it is picked and moved. I'm using the following to resize the cells according to the screen size:

```
[Export("collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:")]
    public CoreGraphics.CGSize GetSizeForItem(UICollectionView collectionView, UICollectionViewLayout layout, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var cellHeight = collectionView.Frame.Height * 0.3;
        var cellWidth = collectionView.Frame.Width * 0.45;
        return new CoreGraphics.CGSize(cellWidth, cellHeight);
    }
```

Single touch on the same cells return correct indexPath, but long press return the indexPath of the cell below the cell being pressed.

Answer (score 0):

This happened because some other view's height was interfering with the collection height.